# How do I update a Bayesian prior using weighted update results?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I have a prior belief about my distribution; I started with $N(10,1)$. Later I received three groups of samples, $X_1$ which is $N(10,2)$, $X_2$ is $N(10.1,3)$ and $X_3, N(9.5,4)$. I also know that the probability of getting samples from the group $X_1$ is 0.7, $X_2$ is 0.2 and $X_3$ is 0.1.

How can I join all the information I have? I would like to obtain a credibility interval. Someone suggested that I use "just another Gibbs sampler" [(JAGS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_another_Gibbs_sampler). Would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "probability of getting samples"? If it is 0.7 then with probability 0.7 the value is correct and with probability 0.3 is incorrect? Or maybe you are talking about some kind of mixture distribution?

Comment: Let's say that my machine produces samples of $X_1$ 70% of the working time etc. So it's the probability of this group, isn't it? 

I know that this problem is not that straight-forward. That's why I ask :)
Thanks for replying.

Comment: You are most welcome, it was my pleasure to do so.

Comment: @mikel I'm afraid it is still unclear. You say that you that you are dealing with mixture distribution of known parameters, what exactly do you want to estimate in here?

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for replying. I would like to take into account all data series and based on that I would like to obtain a credibility interval for the all data I got.

Comment: @mikel it is unclear what your problem is, what kind of data you have and what exactly do you want to estimate. "N(10, 2)" is not a "sample" but it's a distribution, your machine *cannot* produce distributions and the only reasonable reading of this is that you *know* that distribution of outcomes of some machine is N(10, 2) and in such case there is nothing to estimate in here since you already know the answer.

Comment: @Tim, I see what you mean. I used this machine example to make this problem easier to imagine. 
I could have used a weighted mean, but I don't know how to take into account the probabilities. Bayes conjugate seems to be a legit way of joining all the information I have about the generated output.

Comment: @mikel it's not about the machine example but the description of the problem that is unclear. As I said I don't see what exactly you want to estimate in here as you know all the parameters in advance.